# ConfigObj change key=value to key = value which I don't want to

Tags: python, configobj

I have conf file with content:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
font="\"Font\""
```

and it's used like values in bash script.

When I change some value with cgi+python3 and ConfigObj 4.7.0:

```
def set_conf_values(filename, param, value):
    config = ConfigObj(filename)
    config['%s' % param] = value
    config.write()
```

the conf file is rewriten and the format is new:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
font = `\"Font\"`
```

Event for values which is untouched.
That's break my Bash script it takes keys as commands...

I hope there is option to avoid that but can't find such thing in docs.

Comment: Why not do `font="Font"` in your conf file

Comment: I need \" escape.
The problem is that ConfObj add spaces before and after delimiter =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any meaningful way to control the output of ConfigObj. ConfigParser, though, has a [`space_around_delimiters=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.write) keyword argument that you can pass to write.

config.conf:

```
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
font="\"Font\""
```

code:

```
import configparser
from validate import Validator


def set_conf_values(filename, section, param, value):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(filename)

    print({section: dict(config[section]) for section in config.sections()})
    config[section]['%s' % param] = value
    with open('config2.conf', 'w') as fid:
        config.write(fid, space_around_delimiters=False)

filename = 'config.conf'
set_conf_values(filename, 'section1', 'key2','value2_modified')
```

config2.conf (output):

```
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2_modified
font="\"Font\""
```

The dreadful thing about ConfigParser is that it REALLY wants section names. There are elaborate workarounds for this, but this code will get you started.